# Mongodb lookup from the same collection

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, aggregate-functions, lookup

I'm having collection like the below.

Student{

Id

Name

Address

Leader_id(same student)

}
Return type need to be in People format.

So in aggregation I'm doing mapping for those fields.

newAggregation(Aggregation.match(searchCriteria),

Aggregation.project()

.and(name).as(peopleName),

lookupOperation);

Lookupoperation lookupOperation =

newlookup().from("student")

.localField("leader_id")

. foreignField("id")

.as("leaderName");

Each student will contain leader. I.e. student id. I want to get that leader name by looking up again from the same collection. how to write spring data mongo aggregate java code.
I tried with lookup code for get from other collection. It's not working.

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/A7pauDrj2iN) what you want?

Comment: @nimrodserok I tried with same thing. Its Not working. But I'm already querying with aggregate for the same student collection. From the output values, again trying to get the leader name.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.